# WooCommerce / PDF Invoice / Round Tax Rate to one decimal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to ask for help, as I am not a dev and dont understand PHP.
I have the "PDF Invoice" plugin for WooCommerce on my Wordpress site.
And it has a modification to display the tax rate instead of the tax value on the invoice.

```
'<tr>' .
                        '<td valign="top" width="7%" align="left">' . $item['qty'] . ' x</td>' .
                        '<td valign="top" width="13%">' .  $_product->get_sku() . '</td>' .
                        '<td valign="top" width="48%">' .  stripslashes( $item_name ) . '</td>' .
                        '<td valign="top" width="12%" align="right">'  .  wc_price( $item['line_subtotal'] / $item['qty'], array( 'currency' => $order_currency ) ) . '</td>' .                          
                        '<td valign="top" width="10%" align="right">'  .  100 * ( $item['line_subtotal_tax']/$item['line_subtotal'] ) . '%' . '</td>' .  
                        '<td valign="top" width="10%" align="right">' .  wc_price( ( $item['line_subtotal'] + $item['line_subtotal_tax'] ) / $item['qty'], array( 'currency' => $order_currency ) ). '</td>' .
                        '</tr>';
```

The following line is supposed to do the tax rate calculation:

```
     '<td valign="top" width="10%" align="right">'  .  100 * ( $item['line_subtotal_tax']/$item['line_subtotal'] ) . '%' . '</td>' .
```

However, the result shows the tax rate with a lot of decimals, like this 7.67178118746%

So the question is, how can I modify the line above to display only one decimal rounded upwards.
So the result I need there is 7.7%

Thanks in advance and best Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did modify the line above to display only one decimal rounded upwards to get the result like is 7.7%

```
     '<td valign="top" width="10%" align="right">'  .  round( 100 * ( $item['line_subtotal_tax']/$item['line_subtotal'] ) , 1 ) . '%' . '</td>'
```

Thanks :)